# Netbeans 12 and JBoss

Tags: jboss5.x, netbeans-12

Is it possible to add a JBoss 5.x server on Netbeans 12?

When I add a new WildFly server going on *Servers -> Add Server Instance* and I choose the folder where I have the JBoss 5.1.0.GA installed, it keeps saying *"Provide a valid WildFly Location"* and I'm unable to get further.

I can successfully use Eclipse with the same server, but I really wold like to change the IDE

Any help appreciated :)
thanks